# Iterative QuickSort in Doubly Linked List in C

Tags: c, quicksort

I have here a function to quicksort a doubly linked list that uses recursion method. I wonder how can I change this function from recursive to iterative quicksort. I've been trying but I just couldn't get the logic on how it's done.

Edit: I have revised the code and I couldn't get the list sorted. I just followed the algorithm on how quicksort is implemented using array. It has no errors though.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
};

struct Stack
{
    struct Node* top;
};

typedef struct Stack *stackPtr;

struct Node *CreateNode(int data)
{
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->next = newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->val = data;
    
    return newNode;
}

stackPtr CreateStack()
{
    stackPtr stack = (stackPtr)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->top = NULL;
}

void Push(stackPtr stack, int data)
{
    struct Node *newNode = CreateNode(data);
    newNode->next = stack->top;
    stack->top = newNode;   
}

void Pop(stackPtr stack)
{
    struct Node *temp;
    temp = stack->top;
    stack->top = stack->top->next;
    free(temp);
}

struct Node *partition(struct Node *left, struct Node *right)
{
    struct Node *pivot = right;
    struct Node *i = left->prev;
    struct Node *ptr;
    for (ptr = left; ptr != right; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        if (ptr->val <= pivot->val)
        {
            i = (i == NULL ? left : i->next);
            int temp = i->val;
            i->val = ptr->val;
            ptr->val = temp;
        }
    }
    i = (i == NULL ? left : i->next);
    int temp = i->val;
    i->val = pivot->val;
    pivot->val = temp;
    return i;
}
void QuickSort(struct Node *left, struct Node *right)
{    
    stackPtr auxStack = CreateStack();
    Push(auxStack, left->val);
    Push(auxStack, right->val);
    
    while(auxStack->top != NULL)
    {
        Pop(auxStack);
    }
    
    struct Node *pivot = partition(left, right);
    
    if((pivot->val - 1) > left->val)
    {
        Push(auxStack, left->val);
        Push(auxStack, (pivot->val - 1));
    }
    
    if((pivot->val + 1) < right->val)
    {
        Push(auxStack, (pivot->val + 1));
        Push(auxStack, right->val);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->val = 2;
    head->prev = NULL;
    struct Node *l1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    l1->val = 8;
    l1->prev = head;
    head->next = l1;
    struct Node *l2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    l2->val = 3;
    l2->prev = l1;
    l1->next = l2;
    struct Node *l3 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    l3->val = 5;
    l3->prev = l2;
    l2->next = l3;
    struct Node *l4 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    l4->val = 10;
    l4->prev = l3;
    l3->next = l4;
    l4->next = NULL;
    // 2<=>8<=>3<=>5<=>10=>NULL

    QuickSort(head, l4);
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you opened up your favourite search engine and typed in "C iterative quick sort"? But if you have tried something that doesn't work then please show your code and explain what specific problem you have with it.

Comment: I have revised my post. Thanks.

Comment: Your stack doesn't return the popped value. It should, so you can do `right = pop();` `left = pop();`, then partition the list and push non-empty partitions onto the stack. Repeat until the stack is empty. (Of course, the `while` must span all the code I've described above, not just the `pop`.)

Comment: In a recursive quicksort, the input to each recursion is a partition.  Therefore, in an iterative quicksort, the elements that you manage with your stack must be, again, partitions.  A partition is defined by its start and end **positions**, or equivalent data.  You are instead storing the ***values*** of the left and right nodes.  That cannot work, and it should have been a clue to you that you never actually use the the data that you push onto your stack.  I suggest starting with a (working) recursive version and converting it to iterative.

Comment: @MOehm Can I see how it is implemented? I'm quite confused.

Comment: That's actually my problem sir @JohnBollinger I have a recursive quicksort but I cannot understand how it is done iteratively.

Comment: @KEL, it is conceptually simple. When a function recurses, the values of all its local variables are retained in the context of the calling function execution until the call returns.  To replace the recursion with iteration, one needs to replace that automatic preservation of local variables with manual preservation, at least for those local variables whose values need to be retained.  The call is replaced with a branch to the beginning of the function, and the return by restoration of the most recently stored set of local variable values.  Of course, the Devil is in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a working recursive quicksort function:

```
void quicksort_rec(int *a, const int *end)
{
    if (a + 1 < end) {
        int *pivot = partition(a, end);

        quicksort_rec(a, pivot);
        quicksort_rec(pivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```

(This is a quicksort on an array and it takes a range in the form of a pointer to the start and (exclusive) end of the array. Never mind the details of the partition function.)

When you call `quicksort_rec` recursively, the local variables of the called functions are stored on the call stack: Pivots and ranges of "parent" recursions are still available as the recursion depth grows.

If you want to turn this into an iterative function, you must maintain a stack manually. (John Bollinger has described this in more detail and better than I can in the comments.)

So instead of calling `quicksort(a, b)`, you must push `a` and `b` on the stack to "save them for later". The last things pushed on a stack are the first things popped off, so the right-hand array will be sorted next.

Given a stack implementation that stores pointers to `int`, we can turn the recursive function above into an iterative function:

```
void quicksort_iter(int *a, int *end)
{
    Stack stack = {0};
    
    push(&stack, a);
    push(&stack, end);

    while (isempty(&stack)) {
        end = pop(&stack);
        a = pop(&stack);
        
        if (a + 1 < end) {
            int *pivot = partition(a, end);
            
            push(&stack, a);
            push(&stack, pivot);
        
            push(&stack, pivot + 1);
            push(&stack, end);
        }
    }
}
```

This code always pushes or pops two items simultaneously. Note that the begin and end pointers must be popped in the reverse order in which they were pushed. You could also create a struct of pwo pointers and always push one such struct, which may be cleaner. You could also optimize this by not pushing sub-arrays on the stack if they are known to have fewer than two items.

The exact implementation is left to the reader, yadda, yadda, ... `:)` But [here's](https://ideone.com/ujaIc5)  a full implementation of the code above to get you started.